An intuitive GUI for CASTEP instead of Material Studio Visualizer
Would you please suggest intuitive GUI programs for CASTEP instead of Material Studio Visualizer.
For the modelling molecules, I use Avogadro and Avogadro2, and for the visualization of crystalline materials, VESTA. They are really nice. However, CASTEP has actually many options and it is not so easy to choose them correctly for beginners including myself. Are there any GUI programs capable to model efficiently for CASTEP?

+1 but please proofread your post, thoroughly.

I cannot edit my post at this time. I post here an AI-based proofread question. For the modelling molecules, Avogadro and Avogadro2 were used, and for the visualization of crystalline materials, VESTA was used. They are really nice. However, CASTEP has many options, and it is not easy for beginners, including myself, to choose them correctly. Are there any GUI programs capable of efficiently modelling CASTEP? Is this question understandable?

Why can't you just read your question and fix the errors in it yourself, without resorting to AI?

I’m voting to close this question because the author refuses to read its title, which has quite an obvious typo, and instead resorts to using AI, which is banned on most of the SE network.

Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/12814/comprehensive-tutorial-for-castep-without-material-studio-visualizer

I'm sorry, but I did not refuse it, I was just unaware of it. On the use of AI, I did not generate my question, and use it just to improve English. Anyway, I understand a small (in my opinion) mistake is very unwelcome here. So, I will delete this question later. (This comment is not proofread.)

Unfortunately, I could not delete this question with my privilege. Anyway, I leave here because now I understand the StackExchange is for those who are fluent in English, and not for me.

Since you seem to be able to construct and visualise molecules and crystal structures fine (with Avogadro, Vesta etc.) I will assume that you're really asking about the simulation parameters, rather than the geometry of the system. The short answer is that I don't know of any GUIs (aside from Materials Studio) which set the parameters, but I haven't looked very hard; there isn't a huge advantage to using a graphical user interface for the parameters, although it does help when you would like to browse the capabilities.
There are many user interfaces which support CASTEP parameter setting, such as the Atomistic Simulation Environment which has a CASTEP calculator (amongst many others!).
There are also tools such as CASTEPconv which can help you to perform appropriate tests to ensure your simulation results are well-converged with respect to the various numerical approximations, for example the plane-wave cut-off energy.
If you just want to find out which parameters affect a particular property, the quickest way is to ask CASTEP. Suppose you wanted to run a molecular dynamics (MD) simulation, but you weren't sure how to set the MD parameters. To search for a particular word in the built-in help, e.g. 'dynamics', use

castep --search dynamics

This will actually suggest a lot of related keywords, amongst them

MD_NUM_ITER                      number of MD steps
MD_DELTA_T                       MD timestep
MD_ENSEMBLE                      MD ensemble
MD_TEMPERATURE                   MD temperature
MD_THERMOSTAT                    MD thermostat
MD_BAROSTAT                      MD barostat

Now you might like to know more about one of them, for example which ensembles are supported. To do this, you use

castep --help MD_ENSEMBLE

                         MD_ENSEMBLE   *! MD ensemble !*

Type: String                                                       Level: Basic

The ensemble for the molecular dynamics run.
Modifiable: restart only
Allowed values: NVE, NVT, NPH, NPT, HUG, SKT
Default value : NVE

You can also look at the new in-progress CASTEP documentation site, which includes the Materials Studio help documentation for CASTEP, which BIOVIA make available to the community for free.

Thank you so much your answer and I apologize my question is very vague and not specific. I would like to know a GUI program providing fancy dialogs (like Material Studio Visualizer) to choose parameters for structure optimization using DFT. I do agree with you that I must read official and volunteered documents as you kindly suggested. Thanks again. (I will delete this question later as requested.)
